# Visual Studio file viewer that works with TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

We are working on a new web project that is just loose html/css/js files (not an asp site). We want to be able to edit the files in Visual Studio, but not have to have a project/solution file. Ideally, we would have a file system viewer/folder viewer pane instead of the traditional Solution Explorer, and when we opened a file and started to edit it, then it would automatically check the file out.

Is there an extension or something that will give us this functionality easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work off the Source Control Explorer under View Menu -> Other Window -> Source Control Explorer.

Then double click on the html/css/js file and VS will open it with it's default editor.

Comment: Yeah, that is what we are doing now, but when you edit the file, it doesn't silently check out. It shows you a dialog window first.

Comment: VS did automatically check out the file for me when I edit it within VS.  Make sure you have the directory the file resides in mapped locally to your local workspace before viewing it.  Otherwise, VS will open the file in it's temp directory and not auto checkout when you edit.